# Системная клавиатура перекрывает элементы Android 4.4.4 webview

Tags: android, webview

При клике на нижние элементы вертикального списка (divы с c contenteditable true) клавиатура перекрывает div. Сами divы находятся в блоке с position fixed. Если начать печатать div показывается. Пробовал играться с CSS и с манифестом - не помогло. Нужно чтобы клавиатура не перекрывала нижние divы при клике на них

```html
<body> 

<div style="position:fixed; overflow: auto; width:100%; height: 100%; background-color:#00CC99;z-index:1"> 

<div id="show1" align="center" style="overflow-wrap: break-word;width:100%"> 

<div contenteditable="true">erfrewrewr</div> 

<div contenteditable="true">erfrewrewr</div> 

<div contenteditable="true">erfrewrewr</div> 

<div contenteditable="true">erfrewrewr</div> 

<div contenteditable="true">erfrewrewr</div> 

<div contenteditable="true">erfrewrewr</div> 

<div contenteditable="true">erfrewrewr</div> 

<div contenteditable="true">erfrewrewr</div> 

<div contenteditable="true">erfrewrewr</div> 

<div contenteditable="true">erfrewrewr</div> 

<div contenteditable="true">erfrewrewr</div> 

<div contenteditable="true">erfrewrewr</div> 

<div contenteditable="true">erfrewrewr</div> 

<div contenteditable="true">erfrewrewr</div> 

<div contenteditable="true">erfrewrewr</div> 

<div contenteditable="true">erfrewrewr</div> 

<div contenteditable="true">erfrewrewr</div> 

<div contenteditable="true">erfrewrewr</div> 

<div contenteditable="true">erfrewrewr</div> 

<div contenteditable="true">erfrewrewr</div> 

<div contenteditable="true">erfrewrewr</div> 

<div contenteditable="true">erfrewrewr</div> 

<div contenteditable="true">erfrewrewr</div> 

<div contenteditable="true">erfrewrewr</div> 

<div contenteditable="true">erfrewrewr</div> 

<div contenteditable="true">erfrewrewr</div> 

</div> 

</div> 

</body>
```

Comment: интересный вопрос, но много мелочей которые нужно уточнять, сейчас очень тяжело ответить. 
1.Что вы хотите?
2.Какая проблема?
3.Пример, реализация?
4.Какой браузер в WebView
5.Как инжектите CSS, JS в WebView
6.Про какую клавиатуру речь?(Системная, но вдруг)
7.Ну и конечно, покажите HTML, и Java код где все происходит, или как вы считаете проблема.

Answer (score 1):

style="overflow-wrap: break-word;width:100%"> системная клавиатура не подстраивается под приложения . поменяйте значение overflow-wrap width:100% на auto